# NumberFormat Text/currency to display after the Number

Tags: java, gwt

I am displaying a currency symbol with NumberFormat in a textBox

```
          NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getSimpleCurrencyFormat();
          setFormat(numberFormat);
```

and it works ok and displays the currency symbol after the number.

But Now i want to add another symbol in addition to the currency symbol.
so i use this :

```
       String value = currencySymbol+" /Monat";
       numberFormat = NumberFormat.getFormat(value);
```

but then it display this Before my number , Is there any way I can display this text with currency AFTER my number.

Please see the screenshot , I need €/Monat , after 300(dynamic value)

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, your are not using `CurrencyFormat()` anymore, you are using a universal `NumberFormat`. You have to define the the way you want to show the digits in your pattern as well. In case your are not familiar with the symbols I used in the pattern ("#, 0, ¤"), you can check the [java doc for `NumberFormat`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html).

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##0 ¤ /Monat");
String formattedValue = numberFormat.format(300);
```

The output is `300 $ /Monat`.

Comment: No problem! Happy coding. @user1226162